# Setting a property twice while animating

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, uiviewanimation

What happens if I set a property twice to two different values inside of an animation block? If I execute the following pseudocode:

```
myView.frame = CGRectMake(0,  0, 50, 50); // state 0
[UIView beginAnimations:@"showBanner" context:NULL];
{
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:2];
    myView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 20, 50, 50); // state 1
    myView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 10, 50, 50); // state 2
}
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

which of the following results should I get?

1. The frame animates from state 0 through state 1 to state 2.
2. The frame animates from state 0 directly to state 2, ignoring state 1.

I would expect result #2 to happen because I would think that the state of the properties is recorded when the animation is committed. I'm getting a behavior in my app which seems to indicate that result #1 is happening, hence my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the answer is 3. None of the above.

The animation block will only animate the last state change for the property.  So in your case the frame will animate from state 1 to state 2.

Comment: Interesting answer. If that's the case and the first state change happens somewhere inside a library, is my animation doomed to look bad?

Comment: Not necessarily.  Depending on what the library does, you may able to wrap that first state change in its own beginAnimation/commitAnimation transaction.  Within that transaction you can call setAnimationDelegate: and setAnimationDidStopSelector: to identify a method that should get called once the first animation completes.  In that method you can trigger the animation for your second state transition.

Comment: Ideally, I'd like to ignore the first state transition completely. It's actually a knock-on effect from modifying another property and it's causing my desired transition from 0 to 2 to look bad. Any ideas?

Comment: Oh.  In that case, it seems like you could just 1) beginAnimation. 2) Do whatever triggers the transition to state 1 in the library. 3) Manually reset the view back to state 0.  4) Change the view to state 2.  5) commmitAnimation.

Comment: Wouldn't that cause the following animation to occur? 0 -> 1 -> 0 -> 2

Comment: Not if I understand your situation properly.  The library only changes the state?  It doesn't animate the change on its own, does it?  If all three state transitions are wrapped in a single animation transaction, only the last change (0 -> 2) will be animated.

Answer (score 1):

(2) The frame animates from state 0 directly to state 2, ignoring state 1.

Answer (score 0):

I needed an answer to this question and didn't find either one given here satisfactory.  I built a quick test that placed a small subview like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.testView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,40,40)];
    self.testView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [self.view addSubview:self.testView];
}
```

And then provided two alternative animations like this:

```
- (void)animateWithSimpleBlock {

    [UIView animateWithDuration:2 animations:^{
        self.testView.frame = CGRectMake(200,200,40,40);
        self.testView.frame = CGRectMake(  0,300,40,40); 
    }];
}

- (void)animateWithQualifiedBlock {

    [UIView animateWithDuration:2 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState animations:^{
        self.testView.frame = CGRectMake(200,200,40,40);
        self.testView.frame = CGRectMake(  0,300,40,40); 
    }];
}
```

Here's what happens: on `animateWithSimpleBlock`, the testView jumps in a single frame (no animation) from it's initial 0,0 position to the intermediate position 200,200.  From there, it animates over 2sec to the final 0,300 position.

But `animateWithQualifiedBlock` animates the testView smoothly from it's initial 0,0 position to the final 0,300 position.  This is the behavior I need (b/c I'm building up new view positions with looping methods called in the animation block).